# Limits of visualizing $p$-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry

On page 90 of *Gravitation*, Misner Thorne and Wheeler state the following:

*Stacks of surfaces, individually or intersecting to make "honeycombs", "egg crates", and other structures ("differential forms"), give unique insight into the geometry of electromagnetism and gravitation. However, such insight comes at some cost in time.*

What are they referring to? Are there any drawbacks to visualizing differential forms? I was taking this to mean there were mathematical drawbacks not physical drawbacks to such visualizing.

Comment: note that at that time (1970's) differential forms were not wide spread.

Comment: Really? I know nothing of the history. I wonder if learning more would help me understand them. Do you have a preferred resource that covers them?

Comment: beyond what wikipedia collects, "she" has: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#References